# Using project variables in maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I use Spring Boot + Maven. I use the same variables in both Maven POM and application-dev.yml
For example, database properties.

application-dev.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example
    username: user
    password: 12345
    continue-on-error: true
```

POM

```
<spring.datasource.driver-class-name>org.postgresql.Driver</spring.datasource.driver-class-name>
<spring.datasource.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example</spring.datasource.url>
<spring.datasource.username>user</spring.datasource.username>
<spring.datasource.password>12345</spring.datasource.password>
```

I want to delete variables definitions from POM and work with application-dev.yml directly. Please, advice me, how to do it.

Comment: "*I want to delete variables definitions from POM and work with application-dev.yml directly*" - I am not sure that this is possible without furhter setup (I could imagine jinja-templating is able to achieve what you want). But i would not recommend doing this. Overall, there should be no credentials in public available code, e.g. the repository. I would rather recommend externalizing these information.

Comment: Maybe it could be useful http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/

Comment: Can you explain what the exact problem is? I don't understand why you have defined them in pom file as well? Those are only relevant for spring boot in `application-dev.yml` via `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` ? Or if you have packaged the spring boot app ?

Comment: I use this variables in one of maven plugins.